# Installing psycopg2 (postgresql) in virtualenv on windows

Tags: python, postgresql, virtualenv, psycopg2, easy-install

I installed psycopg2 in virtualenv using `easy_install psycopg2`. I did not see any errors and looks like installation went fine.. there is an egg file created in the site-packages dir for psycopg2..

but when I run import psycopg2 in the interpreter, I am getting following error.. any clue? How can I fix it.. any other way to install psycopg2 in virtualenv..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\psycopg2\_psycopg.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\psycopg2\_psycopg.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Edit: this solution is outdated. [Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382801/where-can-i-download-binary-eggs-with-psycopg2-for-windows/5383266#5383266) instead.

I had the same problem. Following the suggestion on [the download page](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) of the Windows port for getting it working on Zope worked for me under virtualenv (also in the non-virtual install):

1. Download the executable, rename the .exe extension to .zip
2. Extract the file contents.
3. Copy the psycopg2 folder to MyEnv/Lib
4. Copy the egg to MyEnv/Lib/site-packages

Comment: You don't need to do this manually. You can just `easy_install http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/psycopg2-2.4.win32-pyx.x-pg9.0.3-release.exe` Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382801/where-can-i-download-binary-eggs-with-psycopg2-for-windows/5383266#5383266) answer.

Comment: Doing this manually is probably a bad idea, as it will make your virtualenv hard to maintain and re-create on other machines.  I'd suggest trying to find a different workaround.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with that other solution. It's a better one.

Comment: There is a pip package on github (disclaimer, I put it together).  Just do: `pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py25#egg=psycopg2`  You can see the full docs at https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked that PostgreSQL's 'bin' directory is on the system path? Check with a quick typing of 'set' and see what you get.

This is the most common cause of import failures of psycopg2 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I used the command `py -m pip install "psycopg2"` and it worked for me.
`pip install psycopg2` didn't work.

[This Link](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) helped me.

Answer (score -3):

There is an alternative to install python packages in your computer i.e, `pip`. You can download python packages by just executing:-

```
    pip install psycopg2
```

The general format of the command is

```
    pip install [package-name]
```

P.S:- To install python packages globally through pip

```
    sudo pip install [package-name]
```