# Where can I download binary eggs with psycopg2 for Windows?

Tags: python, windows, binary, psycopg2, egg

I'm looking for binary eggs with psycopg2's binaries for Windows but can't find any.
On http://initd.org/psycopg/download/ there's only source package and link to [Windows port of Psycopg](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) which provides binary installers but no binary eggs.

The reason I'm looking for binary egg is I'd like to install psycopg in virtualenv and it's <s>not</s> ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/can-i-install-python-windows-packages-into-virtualenvs/5442340#5442340) answer describes why it usually **is** possible) possible with standard Windows installers which look for installed Python in the registry.

Side note: I guess psycopg is rather popular library and it strikes me as odd not to provide binary eggs for download on project's page. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

We just use something like `easy_install http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/psycopg2-2.4.win32-pyx.x-pg9.0.3-release.exe` from within the virtual environment.

Seems to work; we end up with psycopg2 in the virtual environment and not in the base environment, which I take to be the endgame here.

**UPD:** List of available realeases available on [stickpeople.com site](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/)

Comment: it installs the 64x version!! even when you specify 32x

Comment: @siamii It installs the executable you give it. If you're having trouble, I would recommend downloading the version you want first instead of using the URL. Then just give it the file path instead of the URL.

Comment: The mentioned link is no longer up.  See here for psycopg2 installers:  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg

Comment: @DustinWyatt Thanks! Successfully installed psycopg2 into Python's venv using `easy_install c:\Downloads\psycopg2-2.5.2.win-amd64-py3.3.exe`. Also binaries are available at http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

Comment: There is a pip package on github (disclaimer, I put it together).  Just do: `pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py25#egg=psycopg2`  You can see the full docs at https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows

Comment: @DustinWyatt The mentioned link is definitely still up: http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/. It's just that you have to replace "x.x" with the actual Python version.

Comment: @jpmc26 It comes and goes.  When I saw your comment the site was down.  A bit later it was up.  A bit later it was down.  It's up right now.

Comment: I'll just point out that the linked site is the *official* Windows binary, i.e. the one linked from the psycopg FAQ. Christoph Gohlke's repacking, however, is excellent, albeit less directly useable via pip or easy_install.

Comment: The site is down.

Answer (score 3):

Google for "psycopg2 windows" will give you this with the first hit:

http://stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

Repackaging the .exe files is documented here:

[Installing psycopg2 (postgresql) in virtualenv on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030984/installing-psycopg2-postgresql-in-virtualenv-on-windows)

Apart from that: contact the pyscopg2 maintainers and ask to provide windows binaries.

(Dupe)

Comment: Repacking after installation should be fairly trivial.

Comment: If by *repacking* you mean extracting contents of the package and copying it manually then they do it **without** any installation not after. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

For the new guys stumbling upon, stickpeople have these great new pip options on github:
http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/ or 
https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows

Comment: The site is down.

Answer (score 0):

The stickpeople website is down and the exe is no longer available, i have the psycopg2 for python 2.7 and amd64 arch that works for me, you can download it here: [psycopg2-2.5.4.win-amd64-py2.7 20 281 29.exe](https://ossfactory.com/custom_ossfactory/static/src/files/psycopg2-2.5.4.win-amd64-py2.7%20%281%29.exe).