# No module named psycopg2

Tags: python, django, windows-7, psycopg2

I have Django project which uses postgresql 9. I installed psycopg2 and when I run project I receive 'Error loading psycopg2 module: dll load failed'. I met this issue for the first time. I have windows 7 x64 with python2.7. How can I solve this one?

Comment: For me it threw an exception because pip installed package into python 3.8 folder, while I was running python 3.10. If anyone encounters such a problem, they might need to run pip3.10 ... instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, it was that **psycopg2** does not install well in Windows with _easy_install_, I followed the instructions on the follow SO answer:

[Installing psycopg2 (postgresql) in virtualenv on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030984/installing-psycopg2-postgresql-in-virtualenv-on-windows)

You need to manually install the **psycopg2** *exe* file:

psycopg2-2.4.2.win-amd64-py2.7-pg9.0.4-release.exe

Comment: Alternatively download the relevant psycopg2 .whl file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2, then at the prompt ensure you are in your virtual env, and do pip install c:\users\me\downloads\whatever.whl

Answer (score 1):

I know this is going to haunt me again or as [nwcell](https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows) puts it:

> Every time I need to set up psycopg2 on windows, I wind up wanting to shoot something.

I actually have a machine with it working and I've been at pains to setup another machine. I installed Python 3.8 and the old PC has 3.7.4.  The main difference was the file:

**C:\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2_psycopg.cp37-win32.pyd**

On the new PC it was showing as AMD64. I eventually uninstalled 3.8 and reverted back to 3.7.4, then I copied the files from the old PC to the new and then I hit this error:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819509/495455

Going to a WayBackMachine version of the stickpeople:

https://web.archive.org/web/20191003103502/http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

I didn't install the exe, I simply did a `pip install -Iv psycopg2-binary==2.8.4` at which point it started working. So I'm thinking the latest version doesn't work,  for me 2.8.4 still works: https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/#files

It's something to do with x64 as everything I tried with AMD64 didn't work and I spent ages on it.