# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' when running

Tags: python, psycopg2

When I'm trying to run a .py file from the command prompt on Windows 10, I get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'. However, it was installed successfully and works from the interpreter. The conn_test.py file contains only the import psycopg2 statement.

```
C:\Users\212703751>python -m pip install psycopg2-binary
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Using cached psycopg2_binary-2.8.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Successfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.8.6

C:\Users\212703751>python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>> exit()

C:\Users\212703751>conn_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\212703751\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\conn_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

I've tried many approaches, none of them worked.

Do you have any idea, how can I solve this? I'm using Windows 10 x64, and Python 3.7.2

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301424/no-module-named-psycopg2) might help.

Comment: You should list the approaches you have tried

Comment: - `pip install psycopg2`
- `pip install psycopg2-binary`
- `pip3 install psycopg2`
- `pip3 install psycopg2-binary`
- `pip install psycopg2-2.8.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: @JayPatel I already tried `pip install psycopg2-binary`, with the same results: works in the interpreter, not in the command prompt

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue, 'pip install psycopg2-binary' worked for me perfectly.